# Get attribute option value from option_ID

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, eav

I'm getting the child products of a configurable product through this code

```
 $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                        ->getUsedProducts(null,$_product);
```

And in a foreach I'm trying to get a specific attribute value to show up (in this case Storage capacity).

It should display a string like this '32 GB' but instead it is displaying a number like '23'.

```
 foreach($childProducts as $index => $child){
      echo child->getData('storage_capacity'); // Prints 21 or 22 or 23
 }
```

I don't know enough about the EAV resource structure to get the associated value for this attribute. Can anyone push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

try `child->getAttributeText('storage_capacity');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($childProducts as $index => $child){
      echo $child->getAttributeText('storage_capacity');
}
```